# Yesod, howto generate type-safe link from JSON-data in Javascript / Julius

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've a route

```
/notes/#NoteId    NoteR    GET
```

From another page, I want to link to it.
When using "classic" hamlet, it's easy:

```
<a href=@{NoteR $ entityKey note}>notetitle
```

I want my page to be more dynamic and get JSON-data which contains the note-information plus note-id. How do I generate correct *and* typesafe-links?

I've already this code in a `.julius` file, but it fails to compile because it expects a "NoteId". I should insert `obj.id` somewhere in the URL interpolation @{..}... Any clues how to do that?

```
function loadnotes() {
var list = $("#results");
jQuery.getJSON("@{NotesR}",
    function(o){
        $.each(o, function (i, obj) {
            $('<a href=@{NoteR}/>' + obj.title + '</a>').appendTo(list);
        })});
}
window.onload = loadnotes;
```

---

EDIT:

I have this in `Model.hs`:

```
instance ToJSON (Entity Note) where
    toJSON (Entity nid (Note title content created_at updated_at userId)) = object
        [ "id" .= nid
        , "title" .= title
        , "content" .= (unTextarea content)
        , "created_at" .= created_at
        , "updated_at" .= updated_at
        , "userId" .= userId ]
```

Comment: I'm not good with javascript, but as I see it, the `note` value in the hamlet example is a typed haskell value. But `obj` in the julius code is a untyped javascript object. Would it make sense for something without a known type to be part of a type safe url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend having the `NotesR` route return the fully rendered URL instead of just the note ID.

**Edit**: I've added a cookbook entry to demonstrate this approach: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Using-type-safe-urls-from-inside-javascript

Comment: I understand your answer... but how? I had the instance of ToJSON for the the Entity Note (look at edit in question) in `Model.hs`. Is this the adviced place? When adding a line for the url, with `NoteR nid`, I get the error that the data constructor is not in scope... When moving this code into handler-file, it gives another error. What is recomended?

Comment: I've added a cookbook example which I hope demonstrates the approach. Let me know if you have more questions: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Using-type-safe-urls-from-inside-javascript

Comment: Thank you. That cleared things up! I was struggling with getting the proper URL. I was starting of form this example: http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/04/yesod-js-todo (not generating json inside handler). Generating json from inside handler makes more sense when proper url is needed.

Comment: You can still use that style, it just takes a little more work. One approach would be to keep a `Text` field in your datatype for the URL. A fancier approach would be to have a type variable for URLs, and then `fmap` with the render function to go from type-safe URLs to textual URLs. But in this case, it probably makes sense to just keep the code in the handler function.